# Looking for a record iterator for H2O

Tags: iterator, h2o

I wrote the author of a book on H2O and he suggested I post here.

Yes, I know I can use the CSV data before loading into H2O but I don't want to keep duplicate data around.  Yes I know I could use Spark/Sparkling Water, let's pretend I can't for the moment.  I attempted to contact H2O but all I get is salespeople wanting to engage me in a cocktail conversation.

I need to run custom algorithms of all kinds.  There's just no way that H2O can anticipate everything a Scientist might need to do and I don't think H2O is wise in attempting to build (what appears to be) a walled garden.

If I knew the internal format, I could write my own record iterator.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the post so that you're asking a technical question (and remove the narrative & opinions, that's not appropriate for StackOverflow), maybe with some more context about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a concept of a row iterator in quite this way for H2O-3.  The (big, distributed) data is stored in memory in a Distributed Key/Value store in Java.  The computations are done on H2O-3 Frames using Fork/Join underneath the hood, and it's moving the code to the data (via an H2O-3 specific in-memory implementation of MapReduce), not moving the data to the code.

A row iterator would be moving the data to the code.  The closest thing H2O-3 has to that is as.data.frame(), which copies an H2O-3 (distributed, big) data frame to an R data frame.  I would not recommend doing this for large data sets.

Introducing new "custom algorithms" to H2O-3 means writing them in Java using the (public, but developer-intended) H2O-3 API for adding algorithms.  It can definitely be done, but I wouldn't say it's common, and your best guide would be the code.

The complete code for the H2O-3 platform and algorithms implemented in H2O-3 is in github here:

- https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3